# Div wont vertically center in footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

im tring to set up my footer, but cannot for the life of me get it to do what i want. What im trying to do is; have the footer, with a div in the (vertical) center and then have some nav links on the left, a logo in the middle and the date on the right. My main problems are that i cant get the div to (vertically) center, and i cant get the logo to (horizontally) center in the middle of the div.

```
<div id="footer">
            <div id="top"></div>
                <div class="Fcontainer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="date">
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                <!--
                                var months = new Array(
                                "January", "February", "March", "April",
                                "May", "June", "July", "August",                         "September",
                                "October", "November", "December");
                                var currentTime = new Date();
                                var month = currentTime.getMonth();
                                var day = currentTime.getDate();
                                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                                document.write(day + " " + months[month]);
                                //-->
                            </script>
                            </div>

                            <div class="logo">
                                <img src="logo.jpg">
                            </div>

                            <ul class="footmenu">
                                <li>Home</li>
                                <li>Products</li>
                                <li>Our Brands</li>
                                <li>Contact Us</li>
                            </ul>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
.Fcontainer {
    background:grey;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.row {
    background:orange;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#date {
    float:right;
}

ul.footmenu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;

}

ul.footmenu li {
  float: left;

  padding-right: 8px;
}

ul.footmenu li a {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: can you attach a image of an output??

Comment: If I were you I'd look into using flexbox for that kind of layout. It makes things so much easier. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: To elaborate more on @Winters answer... it also makes it more responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this was the description you were looking for. First of all, remove the `float: right` property on the `div` with the ID of `date`.

Then, put `text-align: center` on the `img` with the class of `logo`.

Finally, put the `margin-top: 125px` on the `div` with the ID `footer`. You can modify this amount. Here is a code snippet.

```css
.Fcontainer {
  background: grey;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row {
  background: orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.footmenu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.footmenu li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
ul.footmenu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div class="Fcontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="date">
      </div>

      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.jpg">
      </div>

      <ul class="footmenu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Our Brands</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks yash, that sorted one of my problems. I still cant get the div that contains the three parts to vertically center in the footer. it still sits at the top

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little fiddle that might work for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/9tcxnocb/7/

```css
.Fcontainer {
  background: grey;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  background: orange;
}
#date {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
#date > p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
ul.footmenu {
  flex: 2;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: -40px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.logo {
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div class="Fcontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="footmenu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Our Brands</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://heyba.by/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/CSS3-badge-logo-big.png" height="60">
      </div>
      <div id="date">
        <p>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var months = new Array(
              "January", "February", "March", "April",
              "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
              "October", "November", "December");
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var month = currentTime.getMonth();
            var day = currentTime.getDate();
            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
            document.write(day + " " + months[month]);
          </script>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also take a look at [this](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html).

And as already suggested [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**Edit:** I have edited the code and added and actual image for example purposes. I hope you get the gist of it and will be able to fine tune it.

Answer (score 1):

In Css use the Inspect tool and move the class as your need 
 Dont initialize margin as auto instead of give in pixels which is done by inspect
method

Comment: give a class name for logo then inspect that logo and move it to center

Comment: By giving class name to all the things then move all those thing in this strategy ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.Fcontainer {
background:grey;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: That centers both the logo and the list items, i just want the logo centered

Answer (score 1):

Most wise decision will be

```
<style>
#footer{
  background-image: url(logo.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
</style>

<div id="footer">

</div >
```

Otherwise, you should do this:

```
.logo{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50px;/*according to your center position*/
width: 300px;
margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Comment: only works for the logo, the div is still at the top of the footer